# jquery DataTables horizontal scroll in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, datatables, mozilla

I am using jquery DataTables plugin to format my HTML table. I'm using data-tables directive to tell the library which options I want to use like this:
data-tables="userTableOpts" and define these options in js like this:

```
$scope.userTableOpts = {
 //other options...,
                sScrollY: '50vh',
                sScrollX: '50vh',
                bScrollCollapse: true,
             };
```

However, the horizontal scroll won't appear in Mozilla and the table extends far beyond it's containing element while the vertical scroll is ok. It works perfectly in Chrome and Safari. 
Anyone had a similar problem and how did you resolve it?

Comment: Just add this on your table tag: `style="width:100%"`

Comment: Tried that but DataTables still overides my attribute dynamically to accomodate the length of the content. It gives me the warning in console that it did this though.

Comment: But this is really the heart of the problem cause in Chrome the width attribute stays at 100% (even if I omit it in HTML) but in Firefox it just gives it a value to accomodate the content and ignores the sScrollX option.

Comment: Then try `style="width:100% ! important"`

Comment: It still overides it. I found an ugly solution. I set the width property through "setTimeout" a little after the page loads and datatables messes up the width. It's not only ugly in code but also produces a nasty flickr on page load but I'll take it for now.

Comment: It actually works perfectly if I set the timeout period right! Thanks!

Comment: When i face this issue in the past i think that the solution was `style="width:100% ! important"` and some css rules rewrited :)